# How change username in Identity 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I want crud operation for `Identity user`. When i click on submit button it show me error

> ArgumentNullException: Value can not be null.
>   Parameter name: provider
>   atMicrosoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

**UserController**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind("UserName,Id")] ApplicationUser formuser, string id, string RoleId)
{
    // ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name");
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(formuser.Email);
    user.UserName = formuser.UserName;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if userManager is null?

Comment: your `serviceProvider` is null

Comment: how initialize serviceProvider?

Comment: you should add UserManager to the constructor of your controller so it can be injected for you